# Server config - Is security reduced or compromised if too few SSL cipher options are included?

Tags: security, configuration, openssl

When I input my server version (NGINX 1.16.0) and OpenSSL Version (1.0.2k) into the [Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator](https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/) I get a long list of SSL ciphers.

For example,

`ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;`

However when I visit [Cipherli.st](https://cipherli.st/) it only gives two SSL ciphers for Nginx.

`ssl_ciphers EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM;`

Does having fewer available ciphers reduce or compromise security?  If I offer fewer cipher options to clients does it improve performance or adjust some other important characteristic?

Comment: Cypherli.st links to https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html#toc_1 for their background info and rationale on cipher selection for Nginx and that page seems to list some more ciphers. But in general **fewer ciphers does not compromise on security** (assuming those few ciphers were chosen for their strength and you only leave the strongest) **but on compatibility** as typically older or light weight clients are bad at supporting strong encryption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the allowances in TLS (and SSL before that) is that server and client can (and usually must) negotiate and  agree on a cipher that they mutually support when a secure connection is initiated.

The reason for that is mainly for compatibility: it allows for a gradual introduction of new ciphers rather than breaking connectivity between clients and servers who do not yet support that new cipher.
That is what would happen when only a single cipher would be used, without negotiation. Then,  when one party decides to drop an old cipher and upgrades to a new one and they do that  without coordinating with the other parties connectivity breaks. 
In single organisation coordinating a simultaneous upgrade of both servers and clients is already quite a chore, albeit possible,  on the internet at large such a big-bang upgrade is of course nigh impossible.

Thus: cipher negotiation is good. (For compatibility at least.)

> Does having fewer available ciphers reduce or compromise security?

No. The ***number of ciphers*** does not determine the security.

It is the ciphers themselves that provide the security.

Although some ciphers are relatively more secure than others (different algorithms or the same algorithm with longer key lengths and the ability to provide [forward security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy) can make some more secure than others)  and others are weak or even broken, **there is no additional security benefit in supporting only a few and not all of the ciphers that meet your security requirements.**

(With the slight caveat that each cipher that you support also needs to come with an implementation in software. Thus more ciphers == more code == increased likelihood of bugs and implementation errors...)

> If I offer fewer cipher options to clients does it improve performance or adjust some other important characteristic?

No, although different ciphers will have significantly different performance statistics and different use-cases, with the exception of the caveat above about how fewer ciphers means less code and a lower risk on zero-day exploits, **the *number of ciphers* you support server side does not impact performance** in any relevant way. There is no additional performance benefit in supporting only a few and not all of the ciphers that meet your security requirements.

**Fewer supported ciphers means less compatibility.** (Because you typically restrict servers to the latest and strongest ciphers which older clients may not support and/or which might be too computationally expensive for them.)
Record User-Agent strings and make an inventory on what the impact will be when you update your web servers security settings by referencing a table such as [SSL Lab's User Agent Capabilities](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/clients.html)  beforehand.